# How to send encrypted ids in admin URLs of django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, obfuscation

I have an application which uses django admin interface.  This application allows user to perform CRUD operations on its products.  During these operations, the admin URL exposes the actual ID value of that product like https://localhost/product/1/change.  I'm looking for an option to send the obfuscated ID value shown in URL like https://localhost/product/F87BA2/change.  Can someone please share your thoughts on how to achieve this?

I already have a function that gives a obfuscated value for given ID, but how to use this function in admin URLs which are generated automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the ID always a number? How many digits? If you only want to obfuscate (rather than encrypt) it, simply choosing another decoding might do the job, e.g. Base64 or something the like.

Comment: @nostradamus, yes, ID will always be an autoincremented number.  Basically it is an integer.  Yes obfuscation will be sufficient and I have a function that does this decoding.  But how to make this encoded value to be part of admin URL is my question.  Since these admin URLs are generated automatically, which are the files that will need change/override to make use of this obfuscated values?

Comment: @Malathy you can always redefine the admin urls - but really, why would you want to do this _for the admin_ ??? It's not supposed to be a public part of your site (I mean: it's only ever supposed to be used by trusted internal users - if you want to expose some edition features to non-staff logged in users, you don't use the admin, you write your own forms and views)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, the admin interface is for limited customers to create and/or customize our application based on their subscription with us.  Hence we chose to have django admin interface for those views.  In this case, how can we redefine the admin urls?  Please suggest.

Comment: @Malathy I suggest you do NOT use the admin for this, and build your own set of views and forms instead. From experience (looong experience), it will actually __save__ you a lot of time: trying to do it with the admin, you'll very soon find out __will__ have to write your own views and forms (and urls) anyway, and then you'll have to plug them in the admin, and then override so much of the admin code to make it fit your needs that you'll end up doing much more work than you'd do by just writing your own dedicated app with plain views and forms and templates. My 2 cents...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need slug field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield
It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [**`UUIDField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield), which can be used as unique identification. You can add the `UUIDField` to model like this:

```
import uuid

class Product(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
```

And use it with url like this:

```
# url

path('product/<uuid:unique_id>', views.product, name='product')

# view

def product(request, unique_id):
     product = get_object_or_404(Product, unique_id=unique_id)
```

Also, you can use `UUIDField` as primary key, because(from documentation):

> Universally unique identifiers are a good alternative to AutoField for primary_key. The database will not generate the UUID for you, so it is recommended to use default:

Comment: If I have an ID (autoincremented) field as primary key field and add a UUID field also to be unique, I would like to understand what should be changed in django admin to make the admin URLs use this UUID field instead of default primary key ID to be displayed in URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the answer of Alexander Kononenko (I was not aware of slugfield, thanks for pointing this out), it might still be worth to use a very simplistic approach:

```
import base64

partnr='23'
partobf=base64.b32encode((bytes(partnr, 'utf-8'))).decode('utf-8').replace('=', '')
print(partobf)

# reverse it, if you need to deduce a part number from a given URL
partnrb=base64.b32decode('{}{}'.format(partobf, '='*(8-len(partobf)%8))).decode('utf-8')    
print(partnrb)
```

> Output:
>
> GIZQ
>
> 23

This works for any string (not only numbers) and it is easily reversible. Instead of Base32, you could also use Base64 or any other encoding that uses chars compatible with URLs. Using this method, you can convert any ID from cleartext to obfuscated text without the need of a dictionary, where you have both values stored.

However, it is important to point out that none of this (and also not the other answers present in the thread up to now) have *anything* to do with encryption. So, probably, the OP should change the title.